# Remove color transitions in header of LaTeX beamer Darmstadt theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes, shading, transition

The `Darmstadt` theme of LaTeX's `beamer` class produces color transitions/shadings (?) in the header part, which I find not very nice in certain color combinations. Is there a way to produce clear cuts between the three horizontal areas?

Minimum working sample:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\definecolor{bblue}{rgb}{0.05, 0.15, 0.25} 

\definecolor{rred}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.4}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=bblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=white,fg=bblue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=rred,fg=white}

\begin{document}
\section{Question}
\subsection{Subquestion}

\begin{frame}{I have a question}
\begin{itemize}
\item I do not like the shade in the header
\item I would like all horizontal bars to appear without color transition
\item What can I do about it?
\item Thank you
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Solution (with help from @samcarter): Use the `miniframes` `outertheme`. I also edited the `pgfdeclareverticalshading` for the transition to the main part of the frame.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=white}

\definecolor{bblue}{rgb}{0.05, 0.15, 0.25} 
\definecolor{rred}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.4}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=bblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=white,fg=bblue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=rred,fg=white}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
 {
\usebeamerfont*{headline}
\usebeamercolor{normal text}
\usebeamercolor{title in head/foot}
\usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
\usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
\usebeamercolor{frametitle}

   \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
   color(0ex)=(bblue);%
   color(2ex)=(bblue);%
  color(2ex)=(bblue)%  
  }
 \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@belowframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
  color(2ex)=(rred);%
  color(0ex)=(bblue)%   
  }
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Answer}
\subsection{To the question}

\begin{frame}{That is the solution}
\begin{itemize}
\item Works like this!
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Darmstadt` uses the `smoothbars` outer theme, which is basically the `miniframes` outer theme plus the colour transitions you want to remove. So instead of removing them, I suggest to use the `miniframes` outer theme:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=white}

\definecolor{bblue}{rgb}{0.05, 0.15, 0.25} 

\definecolor{rred}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.4}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=bblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=white,fg=bblue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=rred,fg=white}

\begin{document}
\section{Question}
\subsection{Subquestion}

\begin{frame}{I have a question}
\begin{itemize}
\item I do not like the shade in the header
\item I would like all horizontal bars to appear without color transition
\item What can I do about it?
\item Thank you
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]